# pipe result of cut to next argument and concat to string

Tags: bash, pipe, concatenation, xargs

I have something like:

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 | xargs cat *VAR_HERE.ss
```

where I want to use the result of cut as a variable and concat the output of cut between `*` and `.` so that cat will use the name to output the appropriate file. for example if the result of cut is:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f2
001
```

I essentially want the second command to do:

```
$ cat *001.txt
```

I have seen xargs been used, but I am struggling to find out how to use it to *explicitly* call the output of cut, rather than assuming the second command only requires the exact output. obviously here I want to concat the output of cut to a string.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cat *{}.txt'
```

Comment: @ anubhava. thank you. if I had -f2-3 and passed them, how would I call f2 and f3 explicitly in xargs? it seems that using the {} notation would force them both.

Comment: what i mean is, can i do xargs - I {} {} bash -c 'echo {1} cat*{2}.txt' ?

Comment: You can use `xargs -n 2 bash -c 'echo "<$0><$1>"'` where `$0` and `$1` are first and second arguments.